# Root Activity in task is killed by Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-5.0-lollipop

I have some issue with my Android application. Android kills my Root Activity from my task when the application comes from background to foreground.

When I launch for the first time, the launcher start my SplashScreen Activity to perform some authentication, and will redirect the user at the LoginActivity or HomeActivity.

If the user is correctly authenticated, I start HomeActivity with these flags: `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.

After that, the user can navigate as he wants, all `startActivity` go with a default config for `intent` and `launchMode`, nothing special.

So Let's say we are at this task:

**HomeActivity > UserActivity > FollowerActivity**.

At this moment, I hit the Home Button and start to open new apps, like Facebook, Instagram, Slack, Skype, Twitter. Then finally come back to my application from the Button "Recent Apps". The Application display the last Activity in the task so -> FollowerActivity.
But if I hit the Back Button, instead of go to UserActivity, the application is closed. Android killed my two previous Activities, HomeActivity and UserActivity.

In my AndroidManifest, the HomeActivity have these options:

```
android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
android:launchMode="singleTask"
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
```

I try everything but my Root Activity which is HomeActivity is killed.
I don't know what to do, I try to play with all the flags with Intent and also all params I can put with `<activity />`.

I also save state in every activities and fragment with `OnSaveInstanceState()`, start with primitive type to arraylist of serializable object.

**Do you have any idea how to fix my problem?**

EDIT 1:
When I start to have a lot of activity inside my stack, I get Java Binder Transaction. I think I save too much list of serializable object into my Bundle `savedInstanceState`.
**Can it be the cause of killed activity in my stack ?**

Answer (score 0):

try to define your own onBackPressed()
for the activity instead of the default functionality,
the default would be going back to last activity in stack which is empty, that is why you are kicked out of the app,

Comment: I should define `onBackPressed()` on every activity ? Isn't it too much ? And how I know I am at the bottom for the stack ? With all the options and flags, why my root activity is removed from my stack ? Shouldn't Android keep it and trigger `onCreate()` again ?

Comment: you should not define it on every activity, it is defined by default, if you want/need you should override it.